# FTPConnectionClosedException : Connection closed without indication in BPXBATCH

Tags: java, ftp, mainframe

Below sample code is used with BPXBATCH to Connect to a MAINFRAME FTP Client.
When I run the below from Eclipse on my windows PC. its Successfull.
The issue comes when I try to execute the same with BPXBATCH on a Mainframe.

The code throws an FTPConnectionClosedException : Connection closed without indication
at **client.connect("XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX");**

```
FTPClient client = new FTPClient();  
try {  
    client.connect("XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX");  
    client.login("user1", "pass123");  
    int reply ;  
    reply = client.getReplyCode();  

    System.out.println("Reply Code:"+reply);  

        if(client.isConnected())   
        client.logout();  
        else 
        System.out.println("Negative reply");  
} catch(final Throwable t){  
        t.printStackTrace();  
}
```

Comment: Are there any messages in the mainframe OPERLOG?  Have you checked with the mainframe people to ask if they see anything on their side?  Is the userID and password valid?  Is the account locked?

Answer (score 0):

I believe FTP is not supported in BPXBATCH. You have to use SFTP.